# how to speed up laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, response-time

I have a PHP Application and I use Laravel Framework. When I'm developing the application its response time is not an issue. But, when I deployed it and it gets a lot of data in one of its transaction table (almost 7,000 rows as of this time) in the database it takes of almost 6 seconds to refresh the page. I only get the last 100 data from the database to view as logs. Is there such ways to shorten this response time? BTW my application only run in a local network.

Here is my code:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $users = DB::table('logs')
        ->join('students', 'logs.id', '=', 'students.id')
        ->orderBy('time_in', 'desc')
        ->take(100)
        ->get();

    return View::make('index')
        ->with('users',$users);
});
```

Comment: Which table `time_in` belongs ?

Comment: it belongs to `logs` table

Comment: I just found out the solution. The problem is in the `students` table ids are not set as `PK` means they are not indexed and it would take a lot of time to join them. LOL thanks @AbhikChakraborty.

Answer (score 1):

You should always be checking the query health using `explain select..`

Now from the query that you have in the query builder you will need some indices if not alreay applied

```
alter table logs add index id_idx(id) ;
```

If `id` is a primary key in `logs` table then you do not need the above index

```
alter table logs add index time_in_idx(time_in);
```

The above will be helpful for ordering the data .

If `id` is not a primary key and not indexed either then you may just add the following covering index

```
alter table logs add index id_time_idx(id,time_in);
```

Comment: i think i'll just make the `time in` column primary :-) How about that `explain select...` where i can test it?

Comment: You need to get the raw query and run it on mysql, the query you can check is `explain select * from logs join students on logs.id = students.id order by logs.time_in desc limit 100`